# how to get the value of data-value attr of selected datalist item

Tags: jquery, datalist

here is my `datalist items with data-value attribute`. i want to get the value of data attribute `on change`.

```
 <div class="col-md-3 "> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" list="items" id="proname" placeholder="Product Name" style="margin-left: 12px;"> 
  <datalist id="items">
    <option data-value="120.0">
      Chicken Biryani() 57
    </option>
    <option data-value="100.0">
      chiken manchuriya() 58
    </option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

i want to get the attr value on change of #proname

i tried the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#proname").change(function(){
    var proName=$("#proname").val();

    alert($("#proname option").find(':selected').data('data-value'));//out-put : undefined
  });
});
```

how would i get the `data-value attribute value` . please help me out.

Comment: tried but results is undefined

Comment: for `#proname` change.. you should check `#items` option

Comment: even itried with #items also@ Shwrk

Comment: hi.. can you put the text(eg. Chicken Biryani() 57) in `value` attribute and then try. check this fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/qp32uea9/9/

Comment: updated above fiddle with `data-value` attribute : https://jsfiddle.net/qnqcreaj/3/

Comment: Try this one
$("#proname datalist option").find(':selected').data('data-value')

Comment: its not working with in my case

Comment: @bharath have you checked this fiddle : jsfiddle.net/qnqcreaj/3

Comment: not working @ Aamir Nakhwa

Comment: yes @ Shwrk if i give like value it does not shows actual value like chiken biriiyani it shows value in drop down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code

From

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#proname").change(function(){
        var proName=$("#proname").val();

        alert($("#proname option").find(':selected').data('data-value'));//out-put : undefined

    });
});
```

To

```
$("#proname").change(function(){

  var proName=$("#proname").val();
   var value = $('#items option').filter(function() {
     return this.value == proName;
   }).data('value');
  var msg = value ? value : 'No Match';

alert(msg);

});
```

Comment: what if add another attribute like data-id='10' . how would i get it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data('value')` or `attr('data-value')`

Comment: Can you explain more your answer?

Comment: @RichardAguirre `data()` is specially for data attributes